# What are the correct security settings to use when performing a SOQL query on ContentDocumentLink or ContentVersion?

Tags: apex, soql, sharing, files

We are building a small LWC for browsing images that users have uploaded to our organization through the built-in Files support. Our users are able to properly see the Files when accessed through the Related List Quick Links.

However, if we create an LWC with a SOQL query that queries from `ContentDocumentLink` or `ContentVersion`, then most users (non-administrators) are not able to see any thumbnails.

We believe the issue is because we are using `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED` in our SOQL and these are internal, "system" Objects whose fields cannot be edited by normal users, causing a QueryException. Our Apex controller is annotated with `with sharing`.

If we remove the `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED`, the VSCode is warning us that we are not validating CRUD permissions, understandably.

Our LWC image browser just shows thumbnails of images in a grid view. It is, effectively, read-only.

When querying these Objects, how, if at all, should we be including `WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED` or its relatives `WITH USER_MODE` and `WITH SYSTEM_MODE`?

```
public with sharing class AssetImageBrowserController {

  // getAssetImages
  //
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true scope='global')
  public static List<ContentVersion> getAssetImages(Id assetId) {
    
    // This returns zero results for users that are not system administrators.
    //
    // What would be the appropriate combination of:
    // - Controller sharing annotation
    // - SOQL use of USER_MODE, SYSTEM_MODE, SECURITY_ENFORCED? 

    List<ContentDocumentLink> links = [
      SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocument.Title
      FROM ContentDocumentLink
      WHERE LinkedEntityId = :assetId AND ContentDocument.FileType IN ('PNG', 'JPG', 'JPEG', 'GIF')
      WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
    ];

    // ... snip ...
  }
}
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken the user should habe access to the linkedentityId and if he has then he can actually should see the contentversion. If he doesn't why not make the class without sharing so that it would be visible across all users?

Comment: Have you examined the ContentDocumentLinks to see what the ShareType and Visibility values are? Take a look at the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) for details around these values.